# How to load scripts on url override on new tab in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My manifest.json looks like this.

```
    {
      "manifest_version": 2,

      "name": "Getting started example",
      "description": "This extension shows a Google Image search result for the current page",
      "version": "1.0",

      "chrome_url_overrides" : {
        "newtab": "a.html"
      }
    }
```

I want to include myScript.js and jquery.js on a.html.

I have tried using script tags on a.html( which do not work as inline script not allowed).

Dabbled with content script and background page.But I don't think I need content script here since I am not looking for interaction with current page content.I think this can be accomplished by background page but it does not seem to be working.I have tried adding `"background": { "scripts": ["jquery.js", "myScript.js"] }` to manifest.json but it does not seem to work.

How do I add myScript.js and jquery.js to a.html.

P.S.: All files are in same directory.

Comment: Please provide the `a.html` code, using scripts tags to refer `myScript.js` is supported, which is not `inline script`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding external JS as:

```
<script src="myScript.js"></script>
```

to a.html page and creating myScript.js and writing your JS Code in it.

Comment: how do i use some thing like document.getElementById("Quotes").innerHTML="qwerty";

Comment: on my script page where Quotes is id of a div  on a new tab page.